# Google AppScript check cell value and delete column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I currently have a project where i have to loop through and check 3 different cell values. If the values contain #VALUE1 then it is supposed to delete the column. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I keep getting an error and column never deletes. Also I get a loop error that I can not figure out.

```
function scoreToGrade() {
  var cellsChecked = ['AF2', 'AG2', 'AH2'];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for (var i = 0; i < cellsChecked.length; i++) {
    var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
      .getRange(cellsChecked[i])
      .getDisplayValues();
    console.log(value);
    if (value == '#VALUE!') {
      // do something
      console.log('Not blank ' + value);
      sheet.deleteColumn(cellsChecked + 1);
    } else {
      // do something else
      console.log('is another value ' + value);
    }
  }
}
```

the log is as follows

```
3:41:23 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:41:23 PM  Info    [ [ 'TR' ] ]
3:41:23 PM  Info    is BlankTR
3:41:23 PM  Info    [ [ 'F' ] ]
3:41:23 PM  Info    is BlankF
3:41:23 PM  Info    [ [ '#VALUE!' ] ]
3:41:23 PM  Info    Not blank #VALUE!
3:41:23 PM  Error   
Exception: Cannot convert 'AF2,AG2,AH21' to int.
scoreToGrade    @ Code.gs:115
```

Comment: Have you read the official documentation on `deleteColumn` method?

Comment: Yes I have. I just have trouble figure out how to write the code to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your error appears to be in the line you are using to delete the columns

```
sheet.deleteColumn(cellsChecked+1);
```

You are passing an array of cells to this function instead of the single cell that the method expects. Try passing in a specific array item similar to what you did when getting the value of the cell earlier in your script.

```
sheet.deleteColumn(cellsChecked[i]);
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deletecolumncolumnposition

*Question has changed since posting this reply*

Comment: But the array item is a `string`, not a `number`

Comment: I am not able to add comments to the main post, adding one here instead. Are you looking to delete the whole column if the value inside the second row of the column = '#VALUE!' ?

Comment: rankinj that is correct. Sorry I just saw  your comment

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function scoreToGrade() {
  var cellsChecked = ['AF2', 'AG2', 'AH2'];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for (var i = 0; i < cellsChecked.length; i++) {
    var value = sheet.getRange(cellsChecked[i]).getDisplayValue();
    console.log(value);
    if (value == '#VALUE!') {
      // do something
      console.log('Not blank ' + value);
      sheet.deleteColumn(sheet.getRange(cellsChecked[i]).getColumn());
    } else {
      // do something else
      console.log('is another value ' + value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not get any errors but I do not get the column deleted. If I look at the console.log then it shows nothing for value